# Rails 3 join where query - print only on row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, **Campaigns** and **Orders**

I would like to find a specific campaign with it orders and print all emails.

I tried this in the console but get all the orders data when I only want the row :email

```
Campaign.find_by_id(46).orders(:email)
```

How to print only the emails of those orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Order.where(campaign_id: 46).pluck(:email)
```

This will return an array of emails of orders with specific email

Hope this helps!

Comment: The pluck function is awesome!

Comment: and if you do use yalm like this: "y Order.where(campaign_id: 46).pluck(:email)" you get a nice format output. Do you know how do number every output when using yalm?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect` also:

```
Order.where(campaign_id: 46).collect(&:email)
```